# Running dependent tests in TestNG in logical OR

Tags: java, testng

I have my TestNG tests like below:

```
public class Tests2 {

    @Test(priority = 10)
    public void Test1() {
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test1++++++++++++");
        throw new SkipException("Skipping the test");
    }

    @Test(priority = 20)
    public void Test2() {
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test2++++++++++++");

    }

    @Test(priority = 30, dependsOnMethods  = {"Test1","Test2"})
    public void Test3() {
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test3++++++++++++");
    }
}
```

I want my Test3 to be executed if either of Test1 OR Test2 is passed. The way TestNG is working, it seems like it is always checking if both Test1 AND Test2 are passed. Is there a way that we can change the logical AND to logical OR. I also tried specifying the dependsOnMethods like but on luck

```
dependsOnMethods  = {("Test1"),("Test2")})
```

I also tried dependsOnGroups but that again is checking if all the corresponding tests are passed in logical AND.
Upon running the above tests I am getting the output as:

```
+++++++++Running Test1++++++++++++
+++++++++Running Test2++++++++++++
PASSED: Test2
SKIPPED: Test1
org.testng.SkipException: Skipping the test
    at com.Tests.Tests2.Test1(Tests2.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178)

SKIPPED: Test3

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 2
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

`dependsOnMethods` just tells the order in which unit test will run. It does not mean that those tests should be passed or failed.

You can do it programmatically

```
public class Tests2 {
    private boolean testOnePassed=false;
    private boolean testTwoPassed=false;

    @Test(priority = 10)
    public void Test1() {
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test1++++++++++++");
        testTwoPassed = false// based on your custom condition
        throw new SkipException("Skipping the test");
    }

    @Test(priority = 20)
    public void Test2() {
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test2++++++++++++");
         testTwoPassed = true// based on your custom condition

    }

    @Test(priority = 30)
    public void Test3() {
       if(testOnePassed || testTwoPassed){
        System.out.println("+++++++++Running Test3++++++++++++");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @MSach, I think a dependent test won't run in case the dependee(parent) test is executed and passed. So along with controlling the order of execution it also checks for passed/failed status of the parent test case. Can you please elaborate on your comment.

Comment: The above solution is not working. Test3 won't be executed if either of Test1 OR Test2 is a failure.

Comment: Just remove the dependsOn, keep the priority.  Then it would work.  However, this doesn't seem to be a scalable solution

Comment: Seems like this is the only solution. Get rid of dependency, use priority and programmatically control the flow of tests.

Comment: @GagandeepSharma you just need priority as you want to execute them in order. I have have removed the `depemdsOn`. If you don't want priority  remove it and just keep `dependsOn`. That should also work

Comment: Thanks @MSach. That's exactly how I have implemented it now. Cheers.